# Why can the third person plural also mean ‘you’ like second person but never ‘we‘ like first person?

Tags: conjugación, formalidad, cortesía, persona-gramatical

For this sentence:

- Siento decirles que quedan sin trabajo.

Why can *quedan* **sometimes** mean “**you** are” but never “**we** are”?

Is it because *quedan* is a third-person plural for *quedar*?

Comment: "quedan" is only and always third person plural. It is not quedamos, first person plural.

Comment: Because usted(es)=you, yet is 3rd person. The simple way to remember it is that Spanish people treat each others as kings. Usted comes from "vuestra merced", which could be translated as "your majesty/highness", which would be followed by the usage of the 3rd person in English as well.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're getting confused with the conjugation of the verbs, e.g.

- Yo quedo.
- Tú quedas.
- Él/ella/Ud. queda.
- **Nosotros** quedamos(e.g. **we**'re unemployed)
- Vosotros  quedáis (e.g. "Os habéis quedado sin trabajo")
  https://www.rae.es/dpd/vosotras

---

- (a)**Ellos**, **ellas**, (b)**Uds**. quedan.
  https://dle.rae.es/quedar

> 5. intr. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: Permanecer en su estado, o pasar a otro más o menos estable.
>    e.g.

- a) (Ellos) (Se) Quedan sin trabajo(THEY remained unemployed)(=**Ellos**)
- b) Siento decirles que (se) quedan sin trabajo"(I'm sorry to inform you that YOU are fired)(=**Ustedes**)

Comment: Perhaps the asker’s confusion is related to how for learners, these [fórmulas de tratamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmulas_de_tratamiento#En_espa%C3%B1ol) y del [leísmo de cortesía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo_de_cortes%C3%ADa) may cause a cognitive mismatch between the **logical or semantic** person/number in the second person and the **grammatical** person/number in the third person. Similar disconnects occur with the [plural mayestático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_mayest%C3%A1tico) and related [nosisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism).

Comment: @tchrist My point about this should be on some Meta thing but I don't have the saco to write it up properly. Somehow when a site decides to suspend a person, that also stops them from chatting **on any site**. SE fixed this one for me this time, sort of. But it's some kind of unfixed "thing" on the system, I think.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the formal second person plural (pronoun "ustedes") and any third person plural (pronoun "ellos") are conjugated in the same way, even if they are different persons, *i.e.* second *vs* third. In the example shown, since the pronoun is ommited, and there is no context, it's really not possible to know the person.

For reference:
"quedan" is third person plural if we say "ellos quedan", but formal second person plural if we say "ustedes quedan".

It all boils down to the formal *vs* informal versions of plural "you", which are "ustedes" and "vosotros", respectively.

Comment: ustedes is formal in Spain but not in Latin America.

Comment: @Lambie it is also formal in _some_ countries in Latin America. Even in the same country, specifically Columbia, the use of *usted/ustedes* [changes between regions](https://es.quora.com/C%C3%B3mo-es-el-uso-de-usted-t%C3%BA-en-Colombia-seg%C3%BAn-el-contexto/answer/Aryeh-Zeev-Ben-Abraham-Capella) (also see https://alejandramastrangelo.com/de-vos-o-de-usted/).

Comment: @terdon ustedes is formal in Spain and in Latin America where vosotros is not used, ustedes is the only plural there is for you. It is not informal. It is just the plural.

Comment: @Lambie my point is that Latin America is not monolithic, and there are many regional differences so a blanket statement like "ustedes is not formal in Latin America" is incorrect. The example of Colombia I linked you to above is particularly interesting since there are regional variations in the use of usted even within the same country. In any case, even when _ustedes_ isn't exclusively formal, it is still both the formal mode of address _and_  the informal plural, which (the plural being both the simple plural and the formal mode of address) is a very common pattern (e.g. French, Greek).

Comment: @terdon I understand this very, very well. As I said, in SPAIN, Uds is only formal. Since informal is vosotros. Obviously, then in Latin American Uds is the only plural.  Ergo, it's used in all situations where you are referring directly to plural you. Call it formal/informal if you like.  What I do find **interesting** is hearing Ud. used by a mother to a child in Columbian movies/series. And not just one. Several of them.

Comment: @Lambie exactly. For instance, my Colombian ex wife would call me _tu_ but her sister*usted*. I was just pointing out that your blanket statement that _ustedes_ is formal in Spain and not formal in Latin America is only true for _most_ of Spain (the Canarian dialects [tend to use it instead of _vosotros_](https://www.academiacanarialengua.org/consultas/129/)) and _most_ of Latin America.  The regional variations in the use of usted/es vs vosotros are among the more interesting in the Spanish language so it's a shame to reduce that way.

Comment: Most of Latin America? Where in Latin America is vosotros even used? As far as I know, nowhere. The Canaries, ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131666/discussion-between-terdon-and-lambie).